# What does extent really do in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've been messing around with matplotlib recently both after importing an image and with random data from numpy.  I changed the extent for my graphs to be double max range (i.e. 40x40 for a 20x20 matrix), and yet they still look the same.  I can't find any documentation on what extent truly does in this case.  Does it duplicate my data, interpolate it, or some other function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you are inquiring about the `imshow`'s `extent` keyword argument here.

This is used to define the units of the image in the axes. By default, i.e. without setting the `extent`, the units are exactly the pixels of the array. E.g. if you have an image with 10x10 pixels, the extent is `(-0.5, 9.5, 9.5, -0.5)`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(42)

data = np.random.rand(10,10)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

im = ax.imshow(data)
print(im.get_extent())  # prints (-0.5, 9.5, 9.5, -0.5)
```

[image]

Each pixel is one unit large and integers are the pixel center.

It may however happen that you want to use different units for your image. Possibly you have a calibration made on the data or the data is the result of a calculation where different units are used. In such case the `extent` can be set to determine where in the 2D space of the axes units the image will reside. E.g. if you want your image to *extent* from -300 to 300 in x direction and from 50 to 450 in y direction, you may use `extent=[-300,300,450,50]`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(42)

data = np.random.rand(10,10)

fig, ax2 = plt.subplots()

ax2.imshow(data, extent=[-300,300,450,50])

plt.show()
```

[image]

Due to the default equal aspect (`aspect="equal"`) not only the axes coordinates change to range from -300 to 300 and 50 to 450 now, but also the shape of the image has now become non-quadratic, i.e. has an aspect of `(450-50)/(300+300)=0.666`.

There is a [tutorial on `origin` and `extent`](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/tutorials/intermediate/imshow_extent.html) available, which explains this as well and in addition clarifies how the direction of axes with respect to the image data is determined and manipulated.