# How to use `extent` in matplotlib ax.imshow() without changing the positions of the overlayed ax.text() handles?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, text, heatmap, imshow

I am trying to annotate a heatmap. The [matplotlib docs present an example](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.3/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/image_annotated_heatmap.html#sphx-glr-gallery-images-contours-and-fields-image-annotated-heatmap-py), which suggests creating a helper function to format the annotations. I feel there must be a simpler way to do what I want. I can annotate inside the boxes of the heatmap, but these texts change position when editing the [extent of the heatmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51462728/what-does-extent-really-do-in-matplotlib#). My question is how to use `extent` in `ax.imshow(...)` while also using `ax.text(...)` to annotate the correct positions. Below is an example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import Normalize

def get_manhattan_distance_matrix(coordinates):
    shape = (coordinates.shape[0], 1, coordinates.shape[1])
    ct = coordinates.reshape(shape)
    displacement = coordinates - ct
    return np.sum(np.abs(displacement), axis=-1)

x = np.arange(11)[::-1]
y = x.copy()
coordinates = np.array([x, y]).T
distance_matrix = get_manhattan_distance_matrix(coordinates)

# print("\n .. {} COORDINATES:\n{}\n".format(coordinates.shape, coordinates))
# print("\n .. {} DISTANCE MATRIX:\n{}\n".format(distance_matrix.shape, distance_matrix))

norm = Normalize(vmin=np.min(distance_matrix), vmax=np.max(distance_matrix))
```

**This is where to modify the value of `extent`.**

```
extent = (np.min(x), np.max(x), np.min(y), np.max(y))
# extent = None
```

According to the [matplotlib docs](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.imshow.html), the default `extent` is `None`.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
handle = ax.imshow(distance_matrix, cmap='plasma', norm=norm, interpolation='nearest', origin='upper', extent=extent)

kws = dict(ha='center', va='center', color='gray', weight='semibold', fontsize=5)
for i in range(len(distance_matrix)):
    for j in range(len(distance_matrix[i])):
        if i == j:
            ax.text(j, i, '', **kws)
        else:
            ax.text(j, i, distance_matrix[i, j], **kws)

plt.show()
plt.close(fig)
```

One can generate two figures by modifying `extent` - simply uncomment the commented line and comment the uncommented line. The two figures are below:

[image: Without setting extent]

[image: With setting extent]

One can see that by setting `extent`, the pixel locations change, which in turn changes the positions of the `ax.text(...)` handles. Is there a simple solution to fix this - that is, set an arbitrary `extent` and still have the text handles centered in each box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `extent=None`, the effective extent is from -0.5 to 10.5 in both x and y. So the centers lie on the integer positions. Setting the extent from 0 to 10 doesn't align with the pixels. You'd have to multiply by 10/11 to get them right.

The best approach would be to set `extent = (np.min(x)-0.5, np.max(x)+0.5, np.min(y)-0.5, np.max(y)+0.5)` to get the centers back at integer positions.

Also note that default an image is displayed starting from the top, and that the y-axis is reversed. If you change the extent, to get the image upright, you need `ax.imshow(..., origin='lower')`. (The 0,0 pixel should be the blue one in the example plot.)

To put a text in the center of a pixel, you can add 0.5 to the horizontal index, divide by the width in pixels and multiply by the difference of the x-axis. And the similar calculation for the y-axis.  To get better readability, the text color can be made dependent on the pixel color.

```py
# ... 

extent = (np.min(x), np.max(x), np.min(y), np.max(y))
x0, x1, y0, y1 = extent
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
handle = ax.imshow(distance_matrix, cmap='plasma', norm=norm, interpolation='nearest', origin='lower', extent=extent)

kws = dict(ha='center', va='center', weight='semibold', fontsize=5)
height = len(distance_matrix)
width = len(distance_matrix[0])
for i in range(height):
    for j in range(width):
        if i != j:
            val = distance_matrix[i, j]
            ax.text(x0 + (j + 0.5) / width * (x1 - x0), y0 + (i + 0.5) / height * (y1 - y0),
                    f'{val}\n{i},{j}', color='white' if norm(val) < 0.6 else 'black', **kws)
plt.show()
```

[image: example image]